# I18N : Constants needed in constant (Java/GWT)

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization, constants

I I18N an application. 
Part of it consists in I18N-ing the menus. That is OK.
With GWT I can use the Constants interface.
Now I have to I18N the help for the app, which includes some text referring to Menus.
So in these bigger constants, I need to use the menu constants.

Exemple :
I have a resource in the property file for I18N :

```
menuPlay = Play ...
```

Now I want to define another resource = some help text:

```
howToPlay = In order to start the game, go to the menu ??<resource menuPlay>??
```

In question marks above, I want to use the resource menuPlay.

When I want to translate eg in French, the two resources would be :

```
menuPlay = Jouer...
howToPlay = Pour démarrer le jeu, aller au menu ??<resource menuPlay>??
```

How can I do that (in Java / GWT) ? 
I mean is there an off-the-shelf solution (which I could not find or think of). I don't want to code some specific solution that would combine both --in real time-- based on localized info.
This would help prevent inconsistencies when changing the menuPlay resource : no need to bother on changing the other resource howToPlay (high risks to forget).

Answer (score 1):

Then you property is like

```
menuPlay = Play ...
howToPlay = In order to start the game, go to the menu {0}
```

while using

inorder to get `menuPlay`  then in java you may using like  `resource.menuPlay();`

now inorder to get `howtoPlay`

`resource.howToPlay(resource.menuPlay());` //now  `{0}` replaces with  `Play`

you can do it for no.of arguments

`howToPlay = In order to start the game, go to the menu {0} {1}` ..etc

[see message patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)

Comment: thanks.  I understand that your proposal relies on the _messages_ interface from GWT, _howToPlay_ being a message taking the constant _menuPlay_ as an input parameter. I keep this in mind and will use it as a fallback. However I still hope for a solution that would rely only on constants since I use only constants. The idea would to keep the code free of these concerns: in case of need to change the help, I would not want to get back to code (eg when the help text requires to use more constants than was foreseen at the beginning).